# Javascript variables in django static tag

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates, tags

My situation:
In a Django template I would like to use something like this (currently wrong):

```
<script>
   var myimg1='img1.jpg';
   var myimg2='img2.jpg';
</script>
```

and somewhere else, being context_var a proper context variable:

```
<img src="{% if context_var %}
            {% static myimg1 %}
          {% else %}
            {% static myimg2 %}  
          {% endif %}" />
```

How can I get the same result in a simple way?
There is no simple way to define a template variable within the template, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can define a template variable like this:

```
{% with myimg1="img1.jpg" myimg2="img2.jpg" %}

<script>
   var myimg1={{ myimg1 }};
   var myimg2={{ myimg2 }};
</script>

<img src="{% if context_var %}
            {% static myimg1 %}
          {% else %}
            {% static myimg2 %}  
          {% endif %}" />

{% endwith %}
```

But [Django template philosophy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-invent-a-programming-language) frowns upon such things. To quote:

> The template system intentionally doesn’t allow the following:
>
> - Assignment to variables
> - Advanced logic

It is best to pass them as context variables from your view.